# MySQL - VARCHAR to FLOAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to cast a Varchar data (for example 123,45 or 1040,67) to a Float value in my MySql database..
I don't want to change the values, I want to convert the column by Varchar to Float without losing data

Comment: Yes.. My desired query is without replace.. I have edit the question because I want to change the column type

Comment: can you share your sample schema and data